# Triggering pipeline depending on branch used

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'd like to trigger a pipeline depending on the branch being pushed. The code at present:

**gitlab-ci.yml**

```
variables:
  myvariables....

stages:
  - pp

credentials:
  stage: pp
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"'
      variables:
        VAR1: ${V_A}
        VAR2: ${VB_A}
    - if: '$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"'
      variables:
        VAR1: ${V_B}
        VAR2: ${VB_B}
```

The flint parsing seems fine (so syntactically seems fine), however the correct pipeline is not triggered depending on the branch (so develop/master). Is this the correct usage of rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this syntax to apply rules to your whole pipeline (in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file):

```yaml
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "master"
      variables:
        VAR1: ${V_A}
        VAR2: ${VB_A}
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "develop"
      variables:
        VAR1: ${V_B}
        VAR2: ${VB_B}
```

Comment: Thanks, but although the lint check passes, the pipeline "hangs", so I guess there's a syntax error in there somewhere

Comment: Check for any typo in branch names. For instance, your branch may be `main` rather than `master`.